# Show that if the vector $v \neq 0$, then the matrix H is orthogonal and symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if the vector $v \neq 0$, then the matrix

$
H = I - 2\dfrac{vv^T}{v^Tv}
$

is orthogonal and symmetric.

I know that $v^Tv$ is a scalar, and that $vv^T$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, given that $v$ is an $n$-vector. Anyone any hints?

Comment: I think you mean $0$ (the number) instead of $o$ (the letter). Do you know the definition of an orthogonal matrix and a symmetric matrix? Have you tried plugging in the value of $H$ in those definitions?

Comment: By definition, a matrix $M$ is orthogonal if $M^\top=M^{-1}$ and symmetric if $M^\top=M$. It takes only straightforward computations to verify that $H$ has both these properties. You might find it easiest to prove that $H$ is symmetric first, then use that to prove orthogonality.

Comment: Remark: $H$ is known as the [Householder matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, we can assume that $v$ has length $1$, that is, $v^Tv=1$.

We have $\ H^T=I-2(v^T)^Tv^T=H\ $ and $\ H^2=I-4vv^T+4(vv^T)^2$.

So, what's left is to show that (supposed $|v|=1$) we have $(vv^T)^2=vv^T$.

> $(vv^T)^2=vv^Tvv^T=v(v^Tv)v^T=v\cdot 1\cdot v^T$.